# Animation sequence in android

Tags: android, animation, sequence, chain

I'm new to android programming and i'm stuck with an apparently simple problem.

I'm trying to make a simple animation, when my activity loads up, i need a set of buttons to move from the bottom of the screen to their final position.

Actually i've got all the buttons move at the same time, but i'm not able to make the button "2" move when button 1 its in position. All the buttons move at the same time.

To make things clear this is the sequence that i need:

1. button 1 moves up -> when finished -> button 2 starts to move

And so on for the other buttons.

Here is the code

```
animMoveUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.button_anim);

    btn_magazzino.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
    btn_acquista.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
    btn_vendita.startAnimation(animMoveUp)
    btn_crediti.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
    btn_cassa.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
    btn_calcolatrice.startAnimation(animMoveUp);
```

The XML animation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="500"
android:startOffset="500"/> 
</set>
```

Sorry for the stupid question! Thanks in advance

Comment: Like the answer below, add separate animations objects for each button and add listener.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use animation listener for that. For example

```
animMoveUp.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener
@Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(){
 button2.startAnimation(animMoveUp)      ;
  }
  );
```

There may be syntax errors in my code, so you just set animation listener and add its unimplemented methods. That will solve your problem.